# disable form fields when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In order to see the form I am referring to please go to
http://www.pazzle.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_1&products_id=3

just add that to cart, and press checkout.

That form you see, I am trying to disable the fields below the checkbox when it is checked (the shipping details only). How can I do this?

Sorry I can't copy the code directly as it is too big.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the javascript on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/CPjpt/5/

Flip the checkbox a couple times and you'll see it working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Initalize
    if($("#shippingAddress-checkbox").attr("checked") == "checked")
    {
        $("#shippingField input:not(#shippingAddress-checkbox), #shippingField select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#shippingField input:not(#shippingAddress-checkbox), #shippingField select").removeAttr("disabled");               
    }

    //Setup action
    $("#shippingAddress-checkbox").click(function(){
       if($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")
       {
           $("#shippingField input:not(#shippingAddress-checkbox), #shippingField select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       }
       else
       {
           $("#shippingField input:not(#shippingAddress-checkbox), #shippingField select").removeAttr("disabled");               
       }
    });​
});
</script>
```

Basically when that checkbox is clicked set all of the input fields to have the disabled attribute equal to disabled.  When the box is uncheck remote the disabled attribute.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for writing that up for me it would have taken me months!

I have loaded that script in my .php file and it doesn't seem to be working, do I need to place this code is a specific place?

I'm so sorry to sound amateur I just have very little experience with Jscripts.

Comment: Chrome dev tools tells me the script is being loaded, however there is 1 error - Unexpected Token?

Comment: It is loaded as 'jscript_formdim.js' if that helps :/
I still believe the Unexpected Token error is the cause, I just don't know why the error is occuring. I will check back in case you may know of a solution, thank you!

Comment: @Lewis the code needs to be either in $(document).ready() or after the HTML for your forms on the page.

Comment: Like this?
-
-
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
**JS CODE YOU PROVIDED GOES HERE**
</script>

Comment: No matter where I put this script it will not work. I don't understand it works perfectly in JsFiddle! - Any advice welcome

Comment: @Lewis I've updated my example, put that script instead the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have added this just after my <head> tag. This is a screenshot of my live dev tools... 
http://i47.tinypic.com/357j9sk.png
The error still occurs. The code is definitely correct, the position is definitely correct, I just don't know why it's not happening. Anyway, It may be a Zen cart issue...

Comment: @Lewis At the end of line 26 is a `?`  Delete that character and it should fix the syntax

Comment: It worked! You are the best thank you again. I can't believe all this stress over a '?' !!! Haha